# Android InvalidProtocolBufferException error

Tags: android, android-security, android-securityexception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.me.MyApplication: com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: CodedInputStream encountered an embedded string or message which claimed to have negative size.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7494)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:310)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2281)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8646)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: CodedInputStream encountered an embedded string or message which claimed to have negative size.
```

I got only this error with Galaxy S22.

As far as I searched, some devices from Hawei also face this problem.

How can I solve this?

I tried:

```
<application
...
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
...
```

And upgraded library to:

```
    implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03'
```

But this method didn't solve the problem.